# How to add a Facebook friend via FB iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm trying to let a user 'add a friend' using Facebook's iOS SDK.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"brent",  @"id",
                               nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"friends"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

The dialog opens up but says 'An error occurred with . Please try again later.'

Is there something wrong with the request? Is there a way to get a more detailed error?

Comment: I can't even get the dialog to open! My code is nearly identical to yours. Are you implementing all the delegate methods? I am, but none of them get called.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you cannot add a friend using the Facebook iOS SDK. If you look at the request being sent out you can try calling that from a browser to get a detailed message. In my case, the error is:

```
An error occurred with XYZApp. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 3
API Error Description: Unknown method
Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type
```

What the error message means is that this API call cannot be done from iOS.